# How to customize the gesture recognizer automatically added by SwiftUI .onDrag?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop, gesture-recognition

Is there any way to customize the gesture recognizer used by .onDrag() in a SwiftUI View?  The developer documentation states "applying the onDrag(_:) modifier adds the appropriate gestures for drag and drop to this view" but is silent, so far as I can see, as to how to alter the behavior of those gestures.  Those gestures wait for a longpress before initiating the drag. I would like to reduce that delay to zero.

**Why Required**

The app currently uses a custom DragGesture and .offset(value) to effect a drag.  This strategy requires that the view in which the drag initiates have a greater .zIndex than any view over which an item might be dragged.  Since drags can begin in different views, the .zIndex for each view is managed programmatically through ternary operators.

The .onDrag() functionality puts the dragged item on top of all views regardless of .zIndex.  This behavior is now required due to implementation of a magnification gesture, which requires that the magnified view have a .zIndex below that of the other views or it will cover them as it expands.  If the magnified view is then the source of a drag, the required .zIndex behaviors (high for drag, low for magnification) are incompatible.

I tried using .clipped() on the magnified view, but that prevents the dragged item from appearing outside of that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple developer support responds that there is no way to customize the gesture recognizer automatically added by SwiftUI to .onDrag()

Comment: Have you found any workarounds? I have the exact same problem

Comment: I did not, ended up dropping the magnification feature.